# UItableView delete row using the function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have NSMutableArray "day" which contain (6 NSMutable arrays) arrays contain

```
class Lesson{
    NSString *time1;
    NSString *time2;
    NSString *predmet;
    NSString *namPrepod;
    NSString *zamet;
}
```

I have function to get current week, day, lesson

```
-(Lesson *)lessonInWeek:(int)week inDay:(int)day lessonNumber:(int)lNumber
{
    Week *currentWeek = nil;
    if(week)    
        currentWeek = nechetNedel;
    else        
        currentWeek = chetNedel;

    NSMutableArray *dayArray = [currentWeek.days objectAtIndex:day];
    Lesson *lesson = [dayArray objectAtIndex:lNumber];

    return lesson;
}
```

with this function I show in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
......
 Lesson *item = [[Singleton sharedInstance] lessonInWeek:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex inDay:indexPath.section lessonNumber:indexPath.row];

    ....
    time1.text= item.time1;
    ....

    time2.text= item.time2;
    ....
    predmet.text=item.predmet;
    .....
    namePrepod.text=item.namPrepod;
    ......
    zamet.text=item.zamet;
    ....
```

who can I delete a row with this function without the use of ?

```
if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
if(section==1)
......
```

The function need to edit for delete a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `deleteLessonInWeek:inDay:lessonNumber:` to your singleton class, and call it from your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` implementation:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [[Singleton sharedInstance] deleteLessonInWeek:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex inDay:indexPath.section lessonNumber:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

The implementation iside the `Singleton` could use the same clean pattern of looking up day array, then the lesson inside its day, and then deleting the requested item:

```
-(void)deleteLessonInWeek:(int)week inDay:(int)day lessonNumber:(int)lNumber {
    // Choose odd or even week:
    Week *currentWeek = week ? nechetNedel : chetNedel;
    NSMutableArray *dayArray = [currentWeek.days objectAtIndex:day];
    [dayArray removeObjectAtIndex:lNumber];
}
```

Comment: can you write this function which delete a row?

Comment: @Pavel Sure - it's more or less your own code, with `objectAtIndex` replaced with `removeObjectAtIndex`.

Comment: error on this line    [dayArray removeObjectAtIndex:lNumber];
[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: @Pavel The code tries to remove the item that your code displays. I cannot debug the code for you - after all, it is your app. Somehow, row in the index pass is one, when your model has a single row at index zero.

Comment: all work, the problem was in next. I don't write this line after my function -->        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];